# Xubuntu 11.10 x 64 Sandy bridge (i5 2500k) graphics glitches

Tags: graphics, xubuntu, intel-graphics

I have Xubuntu 11.10 x 64 and i5 2500k CPU (sandy bridge). In some games, e.g. [minecraft](http://www.minecraft.net/) I see glitches. Maybe the problem is in the default Xubuntu drivers? Please Advise.
Also some games like [tuxkart](http://tuxkart.sourceforge.net/) (Designed for Linux) is hanging after a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can vouch for both, Minecraft and the Intel video from the CPU. In my case using Minecraft with an Nvidia or with the Intel sometimes creates so very weird glitches, like I can see the whole world without terrain, or maybe so garbage colors stay on one side of the screen and not leave.

With the Intel video card, I have the Intel Graphics 2000 and it does no work right with 3D stuff, well basically any game. I can use it for working an browsing the internet. Even looking and videos in Youtube but don't start looking for games or everything will hang, not just the application of the game. In my case I am the Graphics 2000, in your case you are the Graphics 3000 but if I am sure, the many updates received in the 12.04 for Sandy Bridge technology will help us with this problems.

I need to add that I have not yet tried the PPAs mentioned by Glauber Cardoso.

Comment: Looking forward to 12.04 release.

Comment: Same here Gasan. Same here. It will solve many small bugs in the hardware that you and I are having (apart from pumping the hardware full of power)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the xorg-edgers repository of experimental drivers to update the drivers for your video card. Because the drivers are not guaranteed the experimental operation, can solve problems but also create new problems, but you sure are using the latest release of the same.

I own a laptop with this graphics card and recently updated the drivers for this repository, where there was no problem. If you want to perform the update run the command `sudo apt-add-repository ppa: xorg-edgers/ppa && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade-y` and restart your computer (`sudo shutdown -r now`). After the restart the driver will be updated.

Your video card also has the technology SNA - Sandy Bridge New Acceleration Architecture that improves some acceleration features. After updating the driver to use this feature enter the command `sudo apt-add-repository ppa: sarvatt / sna-intel && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade-y`